# Dont figure what s the role of the counter in javascript

Tags: javascript, counter, development-environment, slide

I want to create a fullscreen image slider in js so I watched a tutorial and I understand most of it beside the 'counter'.I know that its representing the current image but I don't know how it doing that,  how is assigned.

HERE IS THE CODE

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
    arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
    arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
    current = 0; (!!!!THIS ONE I DON`T UNDERSTAND HOW IT S REPRESENTING THE CURRENT IMAGE!!!

// Clear all images
function reset() {
    for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

// Init slider
function startSlide() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}

// Show prev
function slideLeft() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
    current--;
}
// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (current === 0) {
        current = sliderImages.length;
    }
    slideLeft();
});

// Show next
function slideRight() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
    current++;
}


// Right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
        current = -1;
    }
    slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

!! HERE IS THE LINK FROM TUTORIAL https://youtu.be/7ZO2RTMNSAY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current is being used for the index of the array that contains all the elements with the class name of slide.

It might be beneficial for you to read more about arrays: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: Hello!, Remco i wanna thank you for the answer but i know is used for the index of the array but i don't understand how ''current'' makes the connection with my array

Comment: sliderImages contains all the elements with the class name of slides. In slideLeft the code that's being used is sliderImages[current - 1], this means that the sliderImage on the index of 'current - 1' will be selected. If the variable current is 4, then 4-1 will be the selected index. I hope I've made it more clear now..